# Installing Ubuntu on a new computer

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

Bought a new laptop and wanted to install Ubuntu on it.
When I try to install it says

> you need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 7.4 GB

Now, those 7.4GB are clearly the flash drive - but why would the installer think I'm trying to install ubuntu on the flash drive?
I have installed ubuntu several times before (dual boot), and have never encountered this

Comment: What's on the PC to begin with? If you boot the live USB into "try it" mode, what does gparted show for the drive?

Comment: What brand/model? What video card/chip? Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware. Turned off Secure Boot and Windows fast start up? Installed AHCI drivers into Windows and and changed UEFI settings on drive to AHCI?

Comment: I wasn't clear - the laptop has no OS install (freedos). It's an acer aspire 3 (a315-56-52q6). In case it matters - the SSD is a M.2 variant.  
@OrganicMarble - gparted only shows `/dev/sda` with the 7.4GB boot flash drive.  
@oldfred - As mentioned above, no windows.

Comment: I think i need to change SATA mode from AHCI to RAID, but the option does **not** appear in the bios configuration where it should.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably figured the SATA mode is needed to be changed from RAID to AHCI, but I didn't have the option in BIOS.

The trick is that my *acer* laptop hides that option by default - and can be revealed by using `CTRL+S` in the BIOS *main* tab (this isn't prompted anywhere).

> It is not needed to install windows, just change it to AHCI, if not possible to change press `ctrl+s` on the main tab in BIOS. You better disable secure boot and fast boot.
> -- [Acer Community Forums](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/600016/i-need-to-disable-rst-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-a-blank-aspire-a315-54k)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!